# opengl program compiles but gives error when run (UBUNTU 14.04)

Tags: c++, opengl, ubuntu, mesa

I compiled Opengl by installing the folowing packages through Synaptics Package manager.

```
freeglut3 freeglut3-dev freeglut3-dbg libglew1.5 libglew1.5-dev libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dev
```

This is the output when I run the program.

> X Error of failed request:  GLXBadFBConfig
>
> Major opcode of failed request:  156 (GLX)
>
> Minor opcode of failed request:  34 ()
>
> Serial number of failed request:  42
>
> Current serial number in output stream:  41

---

The input to this

```
(lspci | grep VGA) ; \
(dpkg -l | egrep 'xorg-video|glx') ; \
(ls -l /usr/lib/xorg/modules/{drivers,extensions})
```

gives an output to this

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series]
ii  libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64                                 10.1.0-4ubuntu5                                     amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX runtime
ii  libxcb-glx0:amd64                                     1.10-2ubuntu1                                       amd64        X C Binding, glx extension
ii  libxcb-glx0-dev:amd64                                 1.10-2ubuntu1                                       amd64        X C Binding, glx extension, development files
ii  xserver-xorg-video-all                                1:7.7+1ubuntu8                                      amd64        X.Org X server -- output driver metapackage
ii  xserver-xorg-video-ati                                1:7.3.0-1ubuntu3.1                                  amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI display driver wrapper
ii  xserver-xorg-video-cirrus                             1:1.5.2-1build1                                     amd64        X.Org X server -- Cirrus display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev                              1:0.4.4-1build1                                     amd64        X.Org X server -- fbdev display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-glamoregl                          0.6.0-0ubuntu4                                      amd64        X.Org X server -- graphics acceleration module based on OpenGL
ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel                              2:2.99.910-0ubuntu1                                 amd64        X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-mach64                             6.9.4-1build1                                       amd64        X.Org X server -- ATI Mach64 display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-mga                                1:1.6.3-1build1                                     amd64        X.Org X server -- MGA display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-modesetting                        0.8.1-1build1                                       amd64        X.Org X server -- Generic modesetting driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-neomagic                           1:1.2.8-1build1                                     amd64        X.Org X server -- Neomagic display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau                            1:1.0.10-1ubuntu2                                   amd64        X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-openchrome                         1:0.3.3-1build1                                     amd64        X.Org X server -- VIA display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-qxl                                0.1.1-0ubuntu3                                      amd64        X.Org X server -- QXL display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-r128                               6.9.2-1build1                                       amd64        X.Org X server -- ATI r128 display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-radeon                             1:7.3.0-1ubuntu3.1                                  amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI Radeon display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-s3                                 1:0.6.5-0ubuntu4                                    amd64        X.Org X server -- legacy S3 display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-savage                             1:2.3.7-2ubuntu2                                    amd64        X.Org X server -- Savage display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion                      1:1.7.7-2build1                                     amd64        X.Org X server -- SiliconMotion display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-sis                                1:0.10.7-0ubuntu6                                   amd64        X.Org X server -- SiS display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-sisusb                             1:0.9.6-2build1                                     amd64        X.Org X server -- SiS USB display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-tdfx                               1:1.4.5-1build1                                     amd64        X.Org X server -- tdfx display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-trident                            1:1.3.6-0ubuntu5                                    amd64        X.Org X server -- Trident display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-vesa                               1:2.3.3-1build1                                     amd64        X.Org X server -- VESA display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-vmware                             1:13.0.2-2ubuntu1                                   amd64        X.Org X server -- VMware display driver
/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers:
total 4728
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   10408 مٓی     2 01:55 ati_drv.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   31704 فروري  5 15:32 cirrus_alpine.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   19352 فروري  5 15:32 cirrus_drv.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   27832 فروري  5 15:32 cirrus_laguna.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   23560 فروري  5 15:31 fbdev_drv.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1460976 فروري 10 17:15 intel_drv.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  174648 فروري  5 15:33 mach64_drv.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  140656 فروري  5 15:36 mga_drv.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   44488 فروري  5 15:37 modesetting_drv.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   66544 فروري  5 15:36 neomagic_drv.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  207440 فروري  5 15:38 nouveau_drv.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  356336 فروري  5 15:41 openchrome_drv.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  172456 فروري  5 15:43 qxl_drv.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  108712 فروري  5 15:39 r128_drv.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  432616 مٓی     2 01:55 radeon_drv.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   57656 فروري  5 15:41 s3_drv.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  140848 فروري  5 15:43 savage_drv.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  112192 فروري  5 15:46 siliconmotion_drv.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  547064 اپريل  2 16:01 sis_drv.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   77144 فروري  5 15:45 sisusb_drv.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  189392 فروري  5 15:43 spiceqxl_drv.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   65936 فروري  5 15:45 tdfx_drv.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  142224 فروري  5 15:50 trident_drv.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   27624 فروري  5 15:52 vesa_drv.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  157720 اپريل 10 13:56 vmware_drv.so

/usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions:
total 272
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 277832 اپريل 16 18:38 libglx.so
```

---

for this input

```
glxinfo
```

this is the output

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
    GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_swap_control
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, 
    GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, 
    GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, 
    GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_swap_control, 
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, GLX_SGIS_multisample, 
    GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, 
    GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD CAICOS
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.1.0
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
    GL_AMD_conservative_depth, GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend, 
    GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture, GL_AMD_shader_stencil_export, 
    GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax, GL_AMD_vertex_shader_layer, 
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5, 
    GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, GL_ARB_base_instance, 
    GL_ARB_blend_func_extended, GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_conservative_depth, GL_ARB_copy_buffer, GL_ARB_debug_output, 
    GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float, GL_ARB_depth_clamp, GL_ARB_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend, GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_draw_instanced, GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions, GL_ARB_fragment_shader, 
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GL_ARB_get_program_binary, GL_ARB_half_float_pixel, 
    GL_ARB_half_float_vertex, GL_ARB_instanced_arrays, 
    GL_ARB_internalformat_query, GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata, 
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment, GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, 
    GL_ARB_occlusion_query2, GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object, GL_ARB_point_sprite, 
    GL_ARB_provoking_vertex, GL_ARB_robustness, GL_ARB_sampler_objects, 
    GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map, GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding, 
    GL_ARB_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shader_stencil_export, 
    GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod, GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack, 
    GL_ARB_shading_language_packing, GL_ARB_sync, 
    GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object, GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object_rgb32, 
    GL_ARB_texture_buffer_range, GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc, 
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array, GL_ARB_texture_float, 
    GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge, GL_ARB_texture_multisample, 
    GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, 
    GL_ARB_texture_rg, GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui, GL_ARB_texture_storage, 
    GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample, GL_ARB_texture_swizzle, 
    GL_ARB_timer_query, GL_ARB_transform_feedback2, 
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback3, GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced, 
    GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object, GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_object, GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_shader, GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev, GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate, 
    GL_ATI_texture_compression_3dc, GL_ATI_texture_float, 
    GL_ATI_texture_mirror_once, GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, 
    GL_EXT_draw_buffers2, GL_EXT_draw_instanced, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, GL_EXT_packed_float, 
    GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object, GL_EXT_provoking_vertex, GL_EXT_texture_array, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, GL_EXT_texture_compression_latc, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc, GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc, 
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_integer, 
    GL_EXT_texture_mirror_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, 
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode, GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent, 
    GL_EXT_texture_snorm, GL_EXT_texture_swizzle, GL_EXT_timer_query, 
    GL_EXT_transform_feedback, GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra, 
    GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays, GL_KHR_debug, GL_MESA_pack_invert, 
    GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba, GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp, 
    GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil, GL_NV_texture_barrier, GL_NV_vdpau_interop, 
    GL_OES_EGL_image, GL_OES_read_format, GL_S3_s3tc

OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.1.0
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_AMD_conservative_depth, GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend, 
    GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture, GL_AMD_shader_stencil_export, 
    GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3, 
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5, GL_APPLE_packed_pixels, 
    GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object, GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, 
    GL_ARB_base_instance, GL_ARB_blend_func_extended, 
    GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object, GL_ARB_color_buffer_float, 
    GL_ARB_conservative_depth, GL_ARB_copy_buffer, GL_ARB_debug_output, 
    GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float, GL_ARB_depth_clamp, GL_ARB_depth_texture, 
    GL_ARB_draw_buffers, GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend, 
    GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, GL_ARB_draw_instanced, 
    GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location, GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_program, GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_shader, GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_ARB_get_program_binary, 
    GL_ARB_half_float_pixel, GL_ARB_half_float_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_instanced_arrays, GL_ARB_internalformat_query, 
    GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata, GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment, 
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_multisample, GL_ARB_multitexture, 
    GL_ARB_occlusion_query, GL_ARB_occlusion_query2, 
    GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object, GL_ARB_point_parameters, GL_ARB_point_sprite, 
    GL_ARB_provoking_vertex, GL_ARB_robustness, GL_ARB_sampler_objects, 
    GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map, GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding, 
    GL_ARB_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shader_stencil_export, 
    GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod, GL_ARB_shading_language_100, 
    GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack, GL_ARB_shading_language_packing, 
    GL_ARB_shadow, GL_ARB_sync, GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression, GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc, 
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_add, GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar, GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, 
    GL_ARB_texture_float, GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge, 
    GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_ARB_texture_multisample, 
    GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, 
    GL_ARB_texture_rg, GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui, GL_ARB_texture_storage, 
    GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample, GL_ARB_texture_swizzle, 
    GL_ARB_timer_query, GL_ARB_transform_feedback2, 
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback3, GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced, 
    GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra, GL_ARB_vertex_array_object, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding, GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_program, GL_ARB_vertex_shader, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev, GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev, 
    GL_ARB_window_pos, GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate, GL_ATI_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ATI_separate_stencil, GL_ATI_texture_compression_3dc, 
    GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3, GL_ATI_texture_float, 
    GL_ATI_texture_mirror_once, GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_blend_color, 
    GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, 
    GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract, GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array, 
    GL_EXT_copy_texture, GL_EXT_draw_buffers2, GL_EXT_draw_instanced, 
    GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, GL_EXT_fog_coord, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters, GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, 
    GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, GL_EXT_packed_float, GL_EXT_packed_pixels, 
    GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object, GL_EXT_point_parameters, 
    GL_EXT_polygon_offset, GL_EXT_provoking_vertex, GL_EXT_rescale_normal, 
    GL_EXT_secondary_color, GL_EXT_separate_specular_color, 
    GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, GL_EXT_stencil_two_side, GL_EXT_stencil_wrap, 
    GL_EXT_subtexture, GL_EXT_texture, GL_EXT_texture3D, 
    GL_EXT_texture_array, GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_latc, GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc, GL_EXT_texture_cube_map, 
    GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_env_add, 
    GL_EXT_texture_env_combine, GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3, 
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_integer, 
    GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias, GL_EXT_texture_mirror_clamp, 
    GL_EXT_texture_object, GL_EXT_texture_rectangle, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, 
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode, GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent, 
    GL_EXT_texture_snorm, GL_EXT_texture_swizzle, GL_EXT_timer_query, 
    GL_EXT_transform_feedback, GL_EXT_vertex_array, GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra, 
    GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays, GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip, 
    GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_INGR_blend_func_separate, GL_KHR_debug, 
    GL_MESA_pack_invert, GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba, GL_MESA_window_pos, 
    GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp, 
    GL_NV_fog_distance, GL_NV_light_max_exponent, GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil, 
    GL_NV_primitive_restart, GL_NV_texgen_reflection, GL_NV_texture_barrier, 
    GL_NV_texture_env_combine4, GL_NV_texture_rectangle, GL_NV_vdpau_interop, 
    GL_OES_EGL_image, GL_OES_read_format, GL_S3_s3tc, 
    GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp, GL_SGIS_texture_lod, GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays
```

I cut the rest off since the body limit is 30000 characters and output is over 70000

---

Below is all the source code, and I compiled it by typing this in the terminal:

```
g++ triangles.cpp LoadShaders.cpp -o output -lGL -lglut -lGLU -lGLEW
```

triangles.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "vgl.h"
#include "LoadShaders.h"

enum VAO_IDs {Triangles, NumVAOs};
enum Buffer_IDs {ArrayBuffer, NumBuffers};
enum Attrib_IDs {vPosition = 0};

GLuint VAOs[NumVAOs];
GLuint Buffers[NumBuffers];

const GLuint NumVertices = 6;

//init

void init(void)
{
    glGenVertexArrays(NumVAOs, VAOs);
    glBindVertexArray(VAOs[Triangles]);

    GLfloat vertices[NumVertices][2] = {
        {-0.90, -0.90}, //Triangle 1
        { 0.85, -0.90}, 
        {-0.90,  0.85},
        {-0.90, -0.85}, //Triangle 2
        { 0.90,  0.90},
        {-0.85,  0.90}
    };

    glGenBuffers(NumBuffers, Buffers);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers[ArrayBuffer]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    ShaderInfo shaders[] = {
        {GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "triangles.vert"},
        {GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "triagles.frag"},
        {GL_NONE, NULL}
    };

    GLuint program = LoadShaders(shaders);
    glUseProgram(program);

    glVertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);
}

//display

void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBindVertexArray(VAOs[Triangles]);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, NumVertices);

    glFlush();
}

//main

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(512, 512);
    glutInitContextVersion(4, 3);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
    glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);

    if(glewInit()) {
        cerr << "Unable to initialize GLEW...exiting" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    init();

    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    glutMainLoop();
}
```

vgl.h:

```
#ifndef __VGL_H__
#define __VGL_H__

// #define USE_GL3W

#ifdef USE_GL3W

#include <GL3/gl3.h>
#include <GL3/gl3w.h>

#else

#define GLEW_STATIC

#include <GL/glew.h>

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#  ifdef _DEBUG
#    if (_MSC_VER >= 1600)
#      pragma comment (lib, "glew_static_vs2010_d.lib")
#    else
#      pragma comment (lib, "glew_static_d.lib")
#    endif
#  else
#    if (_MSC_VER >= 1600)
#      pragma comment (lib, "glew_static_vs2010.lib")
#    else
#      pragma comment (lib, "glew_static.lib")
#    endif
#  endif
#endif

#endif

#define FREEGLUT_STATIC

#include <GL/freeglut.h>

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#  ifdef _DEBUG
#    if (_MSC_VER >= 1600)
#      pragma comment (lib, "freeglut_static_vs2010_d.lib")
#    else
#      pragma comment (lib, "freeglut_static_d.lib")
#    endif
#  else
#    if (_MSC_VER >= 1600)
#      pragma comment (lib, "freeglut_static_vs2010.lib")
#    else
#      pragma comment (lib, "freeglut_static.lib")
#    endif
#  endif
#endif

#define BUFFER_OFFSET(x)  ((const void*) (x))

#endif /* __VGL_H__ */
```

LoadShaders.h:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  --- LoadShaders.h ---
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#ifndef __LOAD_SHADERS_H__
#define __LOAD_SHADERS_H__

#include <GL/gl.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif  // __cplusplus

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//  LoadShaders() takes an array of ShaderFile structures, each of which
//    contains the type of the shader, and a pointer a C-style character
//    string (i.e., a NULL-terminated array of characters) containing the
//    entire shader source.
//
//  The array of structures is terminated by a final Shader with the
//    "type" field set to GL_NONE.
//
//  LoadShaders() returns the shader program value (as returned by
//    glCreateProgram()) on success, or zero on failure. 
//

typedef struct {
    GLenum       type;
    const char*  filename;
    GLuint       shader;
} ShaderInfo;

GLuint LoadShaders( ShaderInfo* );

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifdef __cplusplus
};
#endif // __cplusplus

#endif // __LOAD_SHADERS_H__
```

LoadShaders.cpp

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  --- LoadShaders.cxx ---
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include "LoadShaders.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif // __cplusplus

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

static const GLchar*
ReadShader( const char* filename )
{
#ifdef WIN32
    FILE* infile;
    fopen_s( &infile, filename, "rb" );
#else
    FILE* infile = fopen( filename, "rb" );
#endif // WIN32

    if ( !infile ) {
#ifdef _DEBUG
        std::cerr << "Unable to open file '" << filename << "'" << std::endl;
#endif /* DEBUG */
        return NULL;
    }

    fseek( infile, 0, SEEK_END );
    int len = ftell( infile );
    fseek( infile, 0, SEEK_SET );

    GLchar* source = new GLchar[len+1];

    fread( source, 1, len, infile );
    fclose( infile );

    source[len] = 0;

    return const_cast<const GLchar*>(source);
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

GLuint
LoadShaders( ShaderInfo* shaders )
{
    if ( shaders == NULL ) { return 0; }

    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();

    ShaderInfo* entry = shaders;
    while ( entry->type != GL_NONE ) {
        GLuint shader = glCreateShader( entry->type );

        entry->shader = shader;

        const GLchar* source = ReadShader( entry->filename );
        if ( source == NULL ) {
            for ( entry = shaders; entry->type != GL_NONE; ++entry ) {
                glDeleteShader( entry->shader );
                entry->shader = 0;
            }

            return 0;
        }

        glShaderSource( shader, 1, &source, NULL );
        delete [] source;

        glCompileShader( shader );

        GLint compiled;
        glGetShaderiv( shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled );
        if ( !compiled ) {
#ifdef _DEBUG
            GLsizei len;
            glGetShaderiv( shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len );

            GLchar* log = new GLchar[len+1];
            glGetShaderInfoLog( shader, len, &len, log );
            std::cerr << "Shader compilation failed: " << log << std::endl;
            delete [] log;
#endif /* DEBUG */

            return 0;
        }

        glAttachShader( program, shader );
        
        ++entry;
    }

#ifdef GL_VERSION_4_1
    if ( GLEW_VERSION_4_1 ) {
        // glProgramParameteri( program, GL_PROGRAM_SEPARABLE, GL_TRUE );
    }
#endif /* GL_VERSION_4_1 */
    
    glLinkProgram( program );

    GLint linked;
    glGetProgramiv( program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linked );
    if ( !linked ) {
#ifdef _DEBUG
        GLsizei len;
        glGetProgramiv( program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len );

        GLchar* log = new GLchar[len+1];
        glGetProgramInfoLog( program, len, &len, log );
        std::cerr << "Shader linking failed: " << log << std::endl;
        delete [] log;
#endif /* DEBUG */

        for ( entry = shaders; entry->type != GL_NONE; ++entry ) {
            glDeleteShader( entry->shader );
            entry->shader = 0;
        }
        
        return 0;
    }

    return program;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif // __cplusplus
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error code `GLXBadFBConfig` means that the system's display system (X11 server + graphics drivers) does not support the pixel format requested for by your program. This can happen if there are no drivers with OpenGL support installed, or if the requested FBConfig goes beyond the capabilities of the GPU.

#### Update: Actual problem

Now that you posted the code it's easy to see where the problem is: Your system uses the open source `radeon` drivers of the Xorg/DRI/Mesa project. Those driver support only up to OpenGL-3.3 (this is also reported by `glxinfo`):

```
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.1.0
```

However your program asks for a OpenGL-4.3 context

```
glutInitContextVersion(4, 3);
glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
```

This is a request that your system can not satisfy. Hence you're not getting the desired FBConfig.

Note that so far your program uses only functions that are also available in OpenGL-3.3 so I suggest you simply ask for a 3.3 context in your program.

---

In your case I'd wager it's the first case: Your system lacks a proper driver installation.

To further help you, please add the output of the following commands to your question:

```
(lspci | grep VGA) ; \
(dpkg -l | egrep 'xorg-video|glx') ; \
(ls -l /usr/lib/xorg/modules/{drivers,extensions})
```

Comment: @Operative: Ok, seems like all the required modules are installed and in place. Next step to look at is your system configuration. What's the output of `glxinfo` when run from the graphical environment?

Comment: "when run from the graphical environment", I'm not sure what that means should I just type in `glxinfo` into the terminal?

Comment: @Operative: Well you could try doing this outside of an X11 session on a text console and get a error "unable to open display". I don't know if the Ubuntu folks disabled it, but try what happens when you press `CTRL + ALT + F1`, that should put you on a text mode login screen. You can switch between consoles with `CTRL + ALT + F<n>` where `F<n>` are the function keys. Consoles 1 to 6 are usually text, 7 is graphical and the rest unused; but Ubuntu may have configured it differently. Anyway, if you can see a graphical desktop (windows, icons, menus and so on) you're in a graphical environment.

Comment: glxinfo output has been put up, however, I had to cut more than half of the output, you want to see the rest, just tell me, I'll edit the output so that you see the next part, (deleting the first part)

Comment: @Operative: Okay, everything on your system looks fine. So my first guess was wrong. You'll have to show us some source code of your program.

Comment: I've put in the source code. `g++ triangles.cpp LoadShaders.cpp -o output -lGL -lglut -lGLU -lGLEW` I've this is how I compiled the code

Comment: BTW, I don't think it's the code, I got the same output when I compiled and ran code from the first tutorial on this link: http://openglbook.com/chapter-1-getting-started.html

Comment: @Operative: Yes the problem is in your code. See my answer update.

Comment: Thanks, had the same problem running on Ubuntu 14.04 in virtualbox. That solved it.